# Problems with ListView in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I have the following frustrating problem I try to solve for a few days.
My main layout is a Scrollview and I know you cannot scroll to a Listview inside a Scrollview, logically.

But my Listview is inside my NavigationView, so it should? I have seperate Problems:

- If I put "fill_parent" or "match_parent" inside the fist RelativeLayout of my "menu_slide.xml" my Listview only shows the first element, no matter how much I put inside. If I give them a fix height of maybe 1000dp my listview can show every new object inside.
- Second, no matter how much elements inside my Listview, I cant scroll them. (NavigationView is a scrollview?)
- And the last one, if I type into my searchbar to filter inside my Listview it shows the right number of elements it should, but it shows for example if there are two matching elements, the first two elements of my Listview not the two matching elements. Anything ist wrong.

**I want a Listview that saves every object that I'am put inside. A NavigationDrawer that have the same height as my screen an holds that listview, hopefully scrollable.**

Here are my codes:

**activity_main.xml:** (Where NavigationDrawer inside)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/vscroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <RelativeLayout...>

            <LinearLayout...>

            <RelativeLayout...>

</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/menu_slide"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**menu_slide.xml:** (Where ListView and my searchbar inside)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/view_list"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="1000dp" <!-- If I put "match_- or fill_parent inside, my ListView shows only one object.-->
    android:gravity="top|center">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchfield"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:singleLine="true" >
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/alist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search"
        android:background="@color/whitePrimary">
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listText"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/circle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**This Button puts elements into my list:** (Inside my activity_main.xml)

```
        bMyList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(myActivities.contains(thisActivity)){
                    ...Toast
                } else {
                    myActivities.add(thisActivity);
                    String[] row = new String[myActivities.size()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                        row[i] = myActivities.get(i).getShortTitle();
                    }
                    adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, myActivities, row);
                    vList.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
        });
```

**This is my Searchbar listener:** (Inside my NavigationDrawer)

```
searchfield.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                }
            });
```

**And this ist my CustomAdapter:** (To put my object into Listview)

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<NextActivity> listActivities;

    public CustomList(Activity context, ArrayList<NextActivity> allactivities, String[] test) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_layout, test);
        this.context = context;
        this.listActivities = allactivities;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null, true);

        TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_activity_icon);


        title.setText(listActivities.get(position).getShortTitle());
        Picasso.with(context).load(listActivities.get(position).getIconSmallURL())
                .error(R.drawable.activity_icon_small_placeholder)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.activity_icon_small_placeholder)
                .into(imageView);

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

This is want I'm looking for:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mup13ww79aq1e4j/Screenshot_2015-10-03-19-45-58.png?dl=0

Comment: There's way too much code here.  Can you narrow it down to make it easier to answer where the problem is?  I would also recommend breaking down the issues into separate questions, or perhaps solving them one at a time, so you can see how one solution effects the other problems.

Comment: For navigationView Issue check this: http://antonioleiva.com/navigation-view/

Comment: Why aren't you using **app:menu** inside Navigation view to get listview below your custom navigation header..

Comment: @jegesh: I reduced my code a littlebit for you. I dont want to delete to much, because I dont know what is responsible for my problem.

Comment: @oguzhand: I will study this, thank you.

Comment: @Droidwala: Because I cant put a <ListView/> inside a <menu/> it only allows me <group/> or <item/>.

Comment: Is your navigation items list dynamic or fixed?

Comment: dynamic thats the point. The app have only one screen, by clicking a button you change the content of the screen. If the new content is something you want save for later you can put it in a List. So if you start, your List is empty. And while you using, the list becomes bigger and bigger. So you can open the navigationdrawer to scroll, watch or search inside your list an reopen content you saved.

Comment: Okay, now I checked the link from oguzhand, but I think my problem is a little bit to special.